# Slow ActiveRecord query mystery

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, searchkick

This question relates to a Rails API-only application using Searchkick (with Opensearch) and PostgreSQL. Some results are taking a long time to render, and I'm seeing something like this, according to the development log:

Opensearch query time: 10ms.
Postgres query time: 7500ms (it's a "select * from records where id in (1,2,...1000,1001...)).
JSON rendering time: 10ms.
Total time: 12000ms.

So, something appears to take extra time. It's not downloading of assets and the Rails app isn't making any external queries.

I tried setting `load: false` on the initial Searchkick query to avoid the 7.5 second Postgres lookup and that caused the whole thing to take around 60 seconds in the browser!

Here's an example of such a query, performed in the console:

```
3.1.2 :020 > results = Record.search('*', where: { _and: [{:record_type=>["repository", "knowledgebase", "knowledgebase_and_repository"]}]}, load: false)
  Record Search (14602.0ms)  records_development/_search {"query":{"bool":{"must":{"match_all":{}},"filter":[{"bool":{"must":[{"bool":{"filter":[{"terms":{"record_type":["repository","knowledgebase","knowledgebase_and_repository"]}}]}}]}}]}},"timeout":"11000ms","size":10000}

 => #<Searchkick::Relation [#<Searchkick::HashWrapper _id="1809" _index="records_development_20221206123449093" _score=1.0 abbreviation="RNAiDB...
3.1.2 :021 > results.took
 => 638
```

There is a discrepancy here between 638ms reported by Searchkick (presumably the time Opensearch took) and the total of 14602ms. I'd guess it's quicker than the 60 seconds in the browser as it was in a console without any controllers involved, but there appears to be something in the Rails stack that's really slowing things down.

At this point I'm not certain of the best way to find out what.

Comment: Within postgres, yes. There are about 4000 rows in the primary table, but there are joins to other tables (e.g. a record has various labels). I suspect a lot of the time is taken up with ActiveRecord code dealing with that, but can't work out what from the logs.

Comment: I'd confirm your join columns are indexed as well.

Comment: I think they all are, but will check again.

Answer (score 0):

Further investigation led me to Rails Mini Profiler:

https://github.com/hschne/rails-mini-profiler

After some issues* I was able to take a look at the offending requests. There appear to be two problems, as I expected:

1. The `select * from records where id in (...)` query mentioned above. This is Searchkick's doing.
2. Instatiation of GraphQL record types which wrap the data generated by that query.

Step 2 is a loop and though each occurrence is short there are 2k+ records and 3-4 GraphQL objects created each time.

So, how to deal with that (other than throwing more processing power at it) is not currently clear.

(*) Lack of sprocket/railtie requirement in application.rb, need to `config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Flash` to config/environments/development.rb, and finally, modifying the database after running a few queries to change the user_id from ::1 to 127.0.0.1 (to get results to display on the profiler page).

Answer (score 0):

Looking at another query I found that around 8500 milliseconds were reported in the Rails logs for that query (a `select * from records where id in (1...2000)`). This query was trigged by Searchkick after it found the IDs of matching records.

Trying that query in Postgres directly with `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, COSTS)` gave me a planning time of 2.5ms and execution time of 3ms.

In order to determine if the extra time was due to ActiveRecord object instantiation I tried creating the logging files discussed here:

https://dev.to/nejremeslnici/track-and-fix-excessive-active-record-instantiation-2902

That gave me, following the query in question:

Instantiated 1987 records of class Record in 11.245583057403564 ms

...which still doesn't explain how the whole query took over 8 seconds.